# Strategy for making a mobile version of an existing site?

Tags: mobile

I have a site setup with content, themes, plugins, and modified code.

However, I want a mobile version.

I googled this and it looked like there use to be plugins that helped with this, but it seems most have been dis-continued.

Is there a strategy for making a site mobile?

Comment: Do you want the mobile version to be available on separate domain ? like `m.foobar.com`

Comment: It doesn't matter...what ever is easiest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 choices

1. choose a Responsive Theme for your site (Responsive adapts for different screen sizes)
2. choose a plugin (such as WPTouchPro - which is both plugin and theme)
3. build a second site which you access at m.example.com, this duplicates all the content and has its own theme

... there is a 4th option ... being polite... there are dozens of great books and websites about [WordPress & Mobile Web Development](http://rcm-uk.amazon.co.uk/e/cm?lt1=_blank&bc1=000000&IS2=1&bg1=FFFFFF&fc1=000000&lc1=0000FF&t=damiesaund-21&o=2&p=8&l=as4&m=amazon&f=ifr&ref=ss_til&asins=0470889519) like this one from Wrox

Comment: if you are bored and want to list the pros and cons of each?...I would think responsive's adaptable theme would be the easiest.

Comment: that would be totally subjective :) responsive is great but the downside is you have no control over the theme and how it responds.  With Plugin its a mix of both :)

Comment: 4th option is building natively...for the iPhone this would be a Objective C Application.

Comment: Did you get credit for the answer?